# Select Query Case Issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
SELECT  * 
CASE
    WHEN (Employees.End_Date is null) 
THEN select 
        EmpId, 
        Emp_Name, 
        Salary , 
        Start_date , 
        End_dat ,
        DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(Start_Date, INTERVAL 30 DAY), Start_Date) * Salary/30 as 'Total_Salary' 
    from Employees
ELSE Select 
        EmpId, 
        Emp_Name, 
        Salary , 
        Start_date , 
        End_date ,
        DATEDIFF(End_Date, Start_Date) * Salary/30 as 'Total_Salary' 
    from Employees
END
From Employees;
```

I have tried a lot but errors in this query are not getting resolved.

I am trying to differentiate the statements on the basis of if the End Date is null or not in the table.

Comment: Any time you try to resolve errors, those errors should be included in the question. Also the title should be selected better than "Select query case issue", so that other people will find the question easier if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The case clause doesn't work that way. Your query could be greatly simplified as below. Also, column names and table names are quoted using the back tick, not a single quote.

```
SELECT 
    `EmpId`,
    `Emp_Name`,
    `Salary`,
    `Start_date`, 
    `End_dat`,
    IF(`End_Date` is null,
        DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(`Start_Date`, INTERVAL 30 DAY), `Start_Date`) * `Salary` / 30,
        DATEDIFF(`End_Date`, `Start_Date`) * `Salary` / 30) as `Total_Salary`
FROM `Employees`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT  EmpId, 
        Emp_Name, 
        Salary , 
        Start_date , 
        End_dat ,
    CASE
        WHEN (Employees.End_Date is null) 
    THEN DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(Start_Date, INTERVAL 30 DAY), Start_Date) * Salary/30
    ELSE DATEDIFF(End_Date, Start_Date) * Salary/30  END AS Total_Salary

From Employees;
```